# Почему приведение к типу данных unsigned short изменяет ответ перемноженных unsigned long переменных?

Tags: c

Перемножал две переменные **av** и **bptr_l** типа unsigned long.
Они дали большой ответ 1043526445,**carry** изначально ноль,поэтому на её побитовое смещение внимание не обращаю.Но после приведение типов произведение стало меньше,почему это так и не испортит ли это конечный результат умножения?
[image: Первое]

[image: Второе]

Другими словами, почему unsigned long 1043526445 это тоже самое,что и unsinged short 62253

Comment: Больше картинок, меньше кода!! (или таки ознакомтесь как задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , а именно - как привести пример)

Comment: Ну выведите оба числа в двоичном виде и сравните (ладно, hex тоже сойдет). Что там осталось "то же самое"? те самые младшие 2 байта из long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Беззнаковые типы работают по правилам модульной арифметики. Модуль равен 2<sup>n</sup>, где `n` - количество битов в представлении значения данного типа.

У вас, очевидно, тип `USHORT` имеет 16 бит в представлении значения, т.е. он реализует арифметику по модулю 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536. И действительно

```
62253 = 1043526445 (mod 65536)
```

Comment: ,а как было бы правильно выводить значение  массива с такими числами на экран ? В каком формате ?

Comment: @Elvin: Смотря чем выводить? `printf`? "Маленькие" типы при передаче в `printf` преобразуются в `int`. Поэтому для них работают все те же `%d`, `%x` и т.д.

Comment: ,длинное число из библиотеки FLINT/C, хочу проверить результат умножения Карацубы.Просто мне показалось, что неправильный формат вывода может исказить результат.А чем, кроме printf() можно ещё выводить?